# non-static function acting as static

Tags: c++, static-methods, managed-c++, non-static

I have created a class library in managed c++.  As far as I can see there is not static function anywhere, but when calling the methods inside the class from non-managed c++ code, the debugger insists that the method is a static method.  This means that when I try to use "this" to call member functions, I get a System.NullReferenceException.

Has anyone had experience with a non-static function thinking it is a static on?

.h declaration

```
    class __declspec(dllexport) DataManager
    {
    public:
        virtual int DataSize() = 0;
        virtual int DataFileIndexNumber() = 0;
    };

    class __declspec(dllexport) RowIDManager : DataManager
    {
    public:
        virtual int KeyOffset() = 0;
        virtual int KeyFileIndexNumber() = 0;
        virtual bool LoadRecordByKey(int key, HDDBSession hSession = NULL);
    };

    class __declspec(dllexport) Referral : protected REFERRAL_REC, RowIDManager
    {
    private:
        virtual int DataSize() { return sizeof(REFERRAL_REC); }
        virtual int DataFileIndexNumber(){ return FN_REFERRAL_DATA; }
        virtual int KeyOffset(){ return FIELDOFFSET(REFERRAL_REC, ReferralID); }
        virtual int KeyFileIndexNumber(){ return FN_REFERRAL_IDX1; }

    public:
        Referral();
        Referral(const REFERRAL_REC* rec);
        int LoadById(HDDBSession hSession, int refId);

        clip ... other member functions

    };
}
```

c++ code

```
using namespace DataObjectLibrary;


bool RowIDManager::LoadRecordByKey(int key, HDDBSession hSession)
{
    bool retVal = false; 
    HDDBFile hRefFile;

    HDDBSession newSession = hSession;
    if (newSession == NULL)
        newSession = DDB_StartSession(DDB_MULTI_USER);

    hRefFile = DDB_OpenFile(newSession, this->DataFileIndexNumber());
    if (hRefFile)
    { //This if statement throws the exception for the "this->"
        if (DDB_FindRec(hRefFile, this->KeyFileIndexNumber(), &key, this))
            retVal = true;
        DDB_CloseFile(hRefFile);
    }

    if (hSession == NULL)
        DDB_EndSession(newSession);
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's complaining because you're attempting to call a function not in your scope.  You should change this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) RowIDManager : DataManager
...
class __declspec(dllexport) Referral : protected REFERRAL_REC, RowIDManager
```

to this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) RowIDManager : public DataManager
...
class __declspec(dllexport) Referral : protected REFERRAL_REC, public RowIDManager
```

I don't understand all the mechanics of non-public inheritance—just that they're rarely used.